# Fetch friends contacts-mobile/phone number from facebook in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, facebook-fql, facebook-ios-sdk

In my application, I need to fetch the facebook friends contact details such as mobile number/phone number, email address, etc from the user account. I am able to fetch the list of friends of the user first name, last name, fb id and profile pic.

Even in iPhone settings I am not able fetch all the friends contacts. Only very few contacts are able fetched. But in android, I have seen that it downloading all the contacts. Is Apple restricting this.

Can any one help me out to fetch the user friends list and their mobile numbers

Comment: first you get all permisson for get this all data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get Facebook friends email id, number/phone number. What ever details of friends currently you are getting is the only thing Facebook provides about the user friends. ie first name, last name, fb id and profile pic.

[Facebook doc's says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)

> Note: There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends.